# Remove white border between <th> in table

Tags: css, html-table, border

I have this table

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yby37ts/)

I would like to set the th like this but can't do it.

[image]

Taking the oportunity to ask, if anyone knows how to set the striped rows is welcome to answer.

```
   <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Favorite Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jim</td>
      <td>00001</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sue</td>
      <td>00002</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barb</td>
      <td>00003</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

td{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
th
{

background-color:#5e6196;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of cellspacing using css:

```
table {
   border-spacing: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

and to get those stripes:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yby37ts/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4yby37ts/1/)**

OR you can add this in your CSS

```
table { border-collapse:collapse }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4yby37ts/2/)**